# How do we search from Firebase realtime database while ignoring case?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

It turns out that searching through Firebase is case-sensitive, that's why I'm having empty results whenever I search for "hammer". I'm using FirebaseRecyclerOptions for searching and displaying the result in recycleview, code below:

```
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ProductModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").orderByChild("name").startAt(str).endAt(str+"\uf8ff"), ProductModel.class)
                    .build();
```

Is there another way to search through the firebase while ignoring string case?

This is how the firebase looks like, thank you for the advice!
[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors, it just does not display anything. No matter what I type in the search bar, it returns nothing.

Comment: It turns out that searching through Firebase is case-sensitive, that's why I'm having empty results whenever I search for "hammer".